# Create layout dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am building an Android app for a forum and the API they have created returns 'bbCode' for posts and private messages.  Things like `[b]bold text here[/b]` for bold text and `[spoiler]hidden text here[/spoiler]` for hidden text which is then revealed by clicking a button of some kind.  I am building a parser that will create a mapping between raw text `some text to be hidden` and type of component `PostComponent.SPOILER` for example.

How would I go about *inflating* this parsed and categorised data into multiple Android views dynamically, and then proceed to merge them into one view which will be displayed in a list (to display a list of posts like you see in a forum)?

I can think of a few hacks to get this done (like creating a layout for each post component and having each of them in a non-scrollable listview stacked on top of one another), but I can't quite think of a nice efficient solution.

Comment: `LayoutInflater#inflate` and `ViewGroup#addView` would be useful